# Create column based on grouping other values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

I have difficulties formulating my issue.
I have a view which brings these results. There's a need to add a column to the view, which will pair up round-trip flights with identical number.

```
Flt_No  From_Airport    To_Airport  Dep_Date           RequiredResult
124    |LCA             |CDG        |10/19/14 5:00     1
125    |CDG             |LCA        |10/19/14 10:00    1
197    |LCA             |BCN        |10/4/12 5:00      2
198    |BCN             |LCA        |10/4/12 11:00     2
501    |LCA             |HER        |15/8/12 12:05     3
502    |HER             |LCA        |15/8/12 15:15     3
```

I.e. flight 124 is going from Larnaca to CDG, and flight 125 is going back from CDG to Larnaca - they both have to have the same identifier.
Round-trip flights will always have following flight numbers.
I have a bunch of conditions which I won't write now.
Omitting hours is not an option, they're important.
I was thinking `dense_rank()` but I don't know how to create one identifier for 2 flights with different numbers, please help.

Comment: Which pair of flights is assigned value `1` in `RequiredResult`?

Comment: What do you mean by "with identical number"? That roundtrip has 2 different Flt_no?

Comment: @Luk Storms yes it has 2 different Flt_No, and what i need is to add a column which will contain 1 identical number for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is similar to the sample data posted, then the following query should give the required result:

```
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                      WHEN From_Airport < To_Airport THEN From_Airport
                                      ELSE To_Airport
                                   END)
FROM mytable
```

Comment: It really does what i asked for, i just need to figure out how and somehow add the other conditions i have.. thank you!

Comment: @Cat Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Join conditions are not limited to simple equality. Assuming {Flight No, Departure, Destination} is unique on any one day, then a self join should do it:

```
select whatever
from flights outbound
  inner join flights inbound on outbound.flt_no+1 = inbound.flt_no
                          and cast(outbound.dep_date, date)
                              = cast(inbound.dep_date, date)
                          and outbound.From_Airport = inbound.To_Airport
                          and outbound.To_Airpott = inbound.From_Ariport
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer...where's the new column which is my main goal? And won't join just spread the results in rows? I need them to look exactly like in my post

Comment: @Cat Replace "whatever" with the column you want, use the table alases `inbound` and `outbound` to select from each side of the join. (I couldn't do this because you do not define what the "identical number" is).